# ¿Cómo corregir mi código de palíndromo con recursividad en JAVA?

Tags: java, recursión

El código es este, pero me salta **false**, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?, ya que mi código solo está usando el texto sin ninguna otra variable:

```
public static boolean esPalindrome(String texto)
{
  if(texto.length() <= 1)
  {
    return true;
  }else
  {
    if(texto.charAt(0) == texto.charAt(texto.length()-1))
    {
      return esPalindrome(texto.substring(1,texto.length()-1));
    }else
      {
          return false;
      }
  }  
}
```

Y tengo el código `main` donde lo testeo y me sale false a pesar de poner una palabra palindroma como "luz azul" que debería ser la salida true

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("resultado:" + Main.esPalindrome("luz azul"));
}
```

Comment: Cual es el error que tienes? aqui eso es lo importante, decirnos que error te sale cuando compilas el codigo.

Comment: bueno tengo el codigo main donde lo testeo y me sale false a pesar de poner una palabra palindroma como "luz azul" que deberia ser la salida true.

Comment: "luz azul" es false "luzazul" es true

Answer (score 2):

Para comprobar un palíndromo los espacios y los signos de puntuación como las comas no cuentan. Debes eliminar estos caracteres de la cadena antes de llamar a la función.

Puedes eliminar los espacios en blanco con el siguiente codigo:

```
String texto= "luz azul";
texto= texto.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Si necesitas eliminar más caracteres puedes utilizar la expresión regular que desees en el primer parámetro del método replaceAll